# IntelliJ IDEA shows an unresolved dependency in build.sbt despite it being available

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I added a library dependency to my project:

```
libraryDependencies += "io.continuum.bokeh" %% "bokeh" % "0.7"
```

It is correctly resolved when reloading the sbt, but IDEA marks the dependency as unresolved. I can also use the stuff from the dependency. I already tried invalidating the cache and a clean and rebuild, but the error does not go away.

Is this a bug or am I missing anything?

Comment: have you solved this somehow? I can still see the same problem with IntelliJ Idea 2017.2.5